# UITableView shifts down, showing the viewcontroller's view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

My tableView shifts down if sometimes I click on a row or on the textfield below to send a message. The view of viewcontroller shows then, if I go to any viewcontroller from here, all of their content has shifted down and view shows. This issue doesn't go until I restart the app. I have tried self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true, self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false and also the navigationBar is not translucent. The size of my viewcontroller is 835, it is increased due to multiple cells.

[image]

When I open the viewcontroller when there are no rows, it shows the view of viewcontroller instead of empty tableview.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's usually happens when you don't set proper **constraints** on your **tableview** or any super view which holds this content, go to your **storyboard** and check constraints. Also please not their own constraints not the **descendant** **constraints**. Thanks.
if still no luck please explain this question a little bit more. I don't have authority to comment that's why I am answering here. (In case of stackoverflow community issue).

Comment: Well, the constraints seem to be proper. Have a look. [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aYBEcjIw05kmsdkYFG5NwHSE-yIekT_8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Constraints seems to be correct, well you can check about the prototype constraints and constraints of top bar @AnuritaSrivastava

Answer (score 0):

Check your constraints, also check if you don't have any insets ...

`self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`